# Bootstrapping multiple module in Angular 6 via array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend, angular6

is it possible to declare an array and use that to bootstrap multiple components in module.ts.
I was trying something like this

```
    export var initialComponents = [];
    initialComponents.push(AppComponent);
    if(condition) {
      initialComponents.push(IchFooterComponent);
    }
```

and then

```
bootstrap: initialComponents
```

Which gives me the following error

> Error: The module oa was bootstrapped, but it does not declare "@NgModule.bootstrap" components nor a "ngDoBootstrap" method. Please define one of these.

Comment: Have you declared a @ngModule? `@NgModule({ declarations: initialComponents | Array<Type<any> | any[], bootstrap: Array<Type<any> | any[] })`

Comment: yeah i declared ng module

Answer (score 7):

You can customize the bootstrapping via implementing `ngDoBootstrap` as method of `AppModule`.
You can list your components which need to be bootstrapped in the `entryComponents` property of `@NgModule`

```
@NgModule({
    entryComponents: [AComponent, BComponent, ...]
    ...
 })
 export class AppModule {

     constructor() {}

 ngDoBootstrap(appRef: ApplicationRef) {
     if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
         appRef.bootstrap(AComponent, '#app');
     } else {
         appRef.bootstrap(BComponent, '#app');
     }
 }
```

If you need a service, you can access them via dependency injection (put it in AppModule as constructor parameter). But I don't know if there are any limitations to it compared to DI in components or services.
Here are the docs for [ApplicationRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ApplicationRef) and its bootstrap method.

Comment: Saved my day! bootstrap: [condition ? ComponentOne : ComponentTwo] worked in dev mode but ng build --prod was crashing: "Value at position 0 in the NgModule.bootstrap of AppModule is not a reference: [object Object". Builds and works fine after removing "bootstrap: " and implementing via ngDoBootstrap.

Comment: Unfortunately, decorator (like `@NgModule`) content (like `bootstrap`) are very fragile and need to be "very static", especially for build case, when a lot of angular optimisations are used)

Answer (score 0):

Try it again (below is the sample code):

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; // <-- NgModel lives here

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes/heroes.component';

var initialComponents: any[] = []; 

initialComponents.push(AppComponent);
if (true) {
  initialComponents.push(HeroesComponent);
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: initialComponents,
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Try this again:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vimqb1?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: I need to declare multiple components inside bootstrap, just few of them should appear based on condition. Your example is loading app component first then from inside app you are loading heroes component which is not my use case.

Comment: Try putting everything into a condition or outside condition it should work. Thats an array type of declaration. As per my understanding, whatever way it should work.